# Calling c++ in web-services

Tags: c++, web-services, visual-studio, visual-c++, applet

In my mind a webservice is a service that create a link between some applications. What I want to do is calling a c++ program installed on a server into a webservice.

However I have found how to call a webservice in a c++ program but that's not what I am looking for.

How do you call a c++ code into a webservice ( I am using VS2013 btw) and is it relevant to do that.

Comment: You either have to communicate with that webservice via web sockets (and agree with a protocol) or pass through another webservice/protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is : How do you call a c++ code into a webservice ( I am using VS2013 btw) and is it relevant to do that.

A web service is a service accessible remotely, which publishes several "endpoints".

Each endpoint corresponds to a function call (possibly implemented in C++).

To call a webservice endpoint, you must serialize the input parameters of the endpoint in a format accepted by the web service (in practice, this usually means generating a SOAP/XML document that contains the values of the parameters), then sending the serialized document to the server. The server then de-serializes the parameters, calls the function, serializes the result, and sends it as a response.

Webservices publish their endpoints (their accessible/callable APIs) in another XML standard, called WSDL, and public web services are usually listed in a public directory.

For this you will need a networking library usable in C++ (see gSoap), or an implementation of your own, on top of a networking library (see boost::asio).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on in which language your web service is coded.

If it is PHP, see the function [system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) to run another programme that you can code in any language you want (including C++ then).

If it is C/C++ on Linux, see the functions [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)/[exec's](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) to create a new process and run another programme in that new process.

If it is C#, see this [tutorial on Process.Start](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process).

If it is Python, see the [subprocess package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) from the standard library.

Anyway, if your web service is in C++ and that the code you want to execute is in the same programme, you can just do a function call in your web service's method.